# Changing colour of an icon on hover using background-image

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a few social media icons in my footer that need to change from white to yellow when hovered over. I've managed to produce the effect, only that there is an extra undesired icon layered on top and it remains white.

Here is an example of what I've done:

**HTML**

```
<li>
  <a class="facebook" href="link" target="_blank">
   <img src="images/00_social media icons/facebook_white.png">
  </a>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.facebook{
     background-image: url('images/00_social media icons/facebook_white.png');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;}

.facebook:hover{
     background-image: url('images/00_social media icons/facebook_yellow.png');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, by the way, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `div` instead of an `img` for your button, and apply your `background-image` rules to it instead of to the wrapping `a`.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/puqej/3/edit

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="link" target="_blank">
      <div class="facebook">Facebook
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.facebook {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/80');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 40px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.facebook:hover {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/210/90');
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you have the icon both as an independant image within the anchor and as a background image of the anchor. Just remove the img tag (and make sure your anchor has the right size to show the background image)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this in CSS:

```
.facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('images/00_social media icons/facebook_white.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: 20px;
}
.facebook:hover {
  background-image: url('images/00_social media icons/facebook_yellow.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<li>
  <a href="link" target="_blank">
    <div class="facebook">
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

And importantly try not to post uglified code here.